# What is the relationship between a function invocation and the keyword 'this'?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, this, invocation

I am pretty new to JavaScript, and I've just started working with `.apply()` and other methods that use the keyword `this`, and I can tell that `this`  has something to do with the context in which the function is invoked, but I'd really like to understand what exactly `this` is referring to.

The relationship between a particular function invocation and `this`  looks similar to the relationship between an object and a property/method.

Are these two relationships related in anyway?

Comment: `value of the object that invokes the function where this is used.`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword) would help you.

Comment: as objects, functions can have attributes. Inside a function, "this" refers to the function that's currently running. So if a function has a "var a = 1", then "this.a" equals 1. That's a pointless example, but "this" is also an important part of visibility and scoping in javascript.

Comment: Have a look at the [MDN documentation about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: @thatidiotguy: Uh what? There are many objects that are *not* functions.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ECMAScript Language Specification Section 11.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.1) the answer is

> The this keyword evaluates to the value of the [ThisBinding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) of the current execution context.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three cases, which you can consider. The are not described formally but instead simple and intuitive:

**Default context**

If you don't specify the context and invoke a **function** (not method), `this` will be the global object:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this); //window
}
```

**Set context implicitly**

If you invoke a function, which is method of given object `this` will be the object before the last dot:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this);
}

var bar = {};
bar.foo = foo;
bar.foo(); //bar
bar.baz = {};
bar.baz.foobar = foo;
bar.baz.foobar(); //bar.baz
```

**Set context explicitly**

You can change the context using `call`, `apply`, `bind`:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this);
}

foo.call(1); //1
foo.call(window); //window

var bar = {};
bar.foo = foo;
bar.foo.apply(42); //42
```